# Error while compiling hello world program in mpi in C on openSUSE

Tags: c, mpi, opensuse, mpich

PROGRAM :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);    /* starts MPI */
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  /* get current process id */
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);  /* get number of processes */
    printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.4/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lopen-rte
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

command for compilation :`mpicc hello.c -o ./hello`.
I am trying to build a cluster of openSUSE nodes.
So I am testing if mpich2 programs run on every node.

Comment: Check these links, it seems your system is misconfigured (e.g. you are missing some package) http://www.lam-mpi.org/MailArchives/lam/2010/04/14195.php, http://www.lam-mpi.org/MailArchives/lam/2010/04/14196.php

Comment: That's a linker error; you're missing a key library (`libopen-rte.so`).

Comment: k thanks ...i'll fix that .....also on other nodes m getting this error: mpi.h no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

libopen-rte.so refers to OpenMPI, not MPICH2. Check default MPI implementation using mpi-selector tool. I personally prefer OpenMPI.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two MPI libraries installed at the same time. While this is possible, it's usually a pain to configure and use if you're not very careful. I'd suggest uninstalling either Open MPI or MPICH. That should take care of your problem.